# How to set no of columns in Jquery UI's Sortable(grid)?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the sortable code directly copied from the demo code provided at their webpage: [source](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Display as grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js">
 </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
#sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width:100px; height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
  </style>
  <script>
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
   </head>
    <body>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>
```

It currently arranges the listitems in a grid of four columns.Where is this code for determining the column count, or how to change it ?I've seen some examples using sortable-grid, but couldnt find where the no of columns is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column count is determined by the `width` CSS property of the `#sortable` `ul`. For example, changing this from `450px` to `540px` will add another column. The width of the `li` elements also determines how many columns will be displayed.

So there's no option or anything like that, it's entirely controlled through CSS.